# Android x86 system files "Read-Only", magisk installation

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu, android-x86, xposed

I want to change the kernel and ramdisk.img file to install magisk, however, the folder is "read-only"

My setup:

- Android-x86_9.0-r2_(x8) running on Proxmox (using QEMU and qcow2
  formatted image)
- GRUB, GBT installed, and I selected install with
  write permissions at the android installation

I tried to install magisk using the following guide: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-android-x86-rooted-magisk-t4077477

I successfully patched the boot.img and got the new kernel and ramdisk.img file. However, I wanted to replace them now, but I get the following error when I want to modify something in the folder where the old kernel and ramdisk.img is located:

```
Read-only file system
```

I connected to android using ADB (but also tried the terminal emulator on android itself). I already tried adb remount and other mounting options, but nothing works. Android runs as root.

The folder where the ramdisk.img and boot is located: */mnt/media_rw/Android-x86_9.0-r2_(x86)/*

When running

```
mount | grep mnt
```

I receive the following (which means the folder Android-x86_9.0-r2_(x86) where the ramdisk.img etc. is stored is read-only:

```
/dev/block/vold/public:11,0 on /mnt/media_rw/Android-x86_9.0-r2_(x86) type iso9660 (ro,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nojoliet,utf8,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1023,gid=1023)
```

When I try to mount it to rw using:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/vold/public:11,0 /mnt/media_rw/Andro*
```

I get:

```
'/dev/block/vold/public:11,0' is read-only
```

What can I do to change the ramdisk.img and kernel so I can install magisk?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Outside of the running Android system you can unpack, edit and repack the image. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69954/how-to-unpack-and-edit-boot-img-for-rom-porting

Comment: Thank you very much, will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. All you can do install gearlock and  find the img somewhere in gearlock/gearrot folder. You can modify that files as you want.
More info:
https://github.com/axonasif/gearlock